# How to save javascript array as redis list

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

The following code save the whole array as single value in redis list. But I want to save array values individually. How can I do it?

P.S So sorry for poor English.

```
var redis = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient();

var arr = [1,2,3];

client.rpush('testlist',arr);
```

Comment: You want to iterate through the array elements and insert them individually. You can write a simple `for` loop or use `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `multi()` to pipeline multiple commands at once:

```
var redis = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient();

var arr = [1,2,3];

var multi = client.multi()

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    multi.rpush('testlist', arr[i]);
}

multi.exec(function(errors, results) {

})
```

And finally call `exec()` to send the commands to redis.

Comment: Using redis-node that wasn't working for me, slightly modified here: https://gist.github.com/vainrobot/141b2162e1200f7c7855

Answer (score 9):

Even if @gimenete answer works, the best way to do what you want is to forward the list elements as arguments to rpush like so:

```
var redis = require('redis'),
    client = redis.createClient();

var arr = [1,2,3];
client.rpush.apply(client, ['testlist'].concat(arr));

// ... or with a callback
client.rpush.apply(client, ['testlist'].concat(arr).concat(function(err, ok){
  console.log(err, ok);
}));
```

**Pros**:
- a single instruction will be transmited to Redis

**Cons**:
- a corner-case: `.apply` will throw a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` if the arguments list length passed to rpush is too large (a little over 100 000 items for v8).

From MDC:

> The consequences of applying a function with too many arguments
>   (think more than tens of thousands of arguments) vary across engines
>   (JavaScriptCore has hard-coded argument limit of 65536), because the
>   limit (indeed even the nature of any excessively-large-stack behavior)
>   is unspecified. Some engines will throw an exception. More
>   perniciously, others will arbitrarily limit the number of arguments
>   actually passed to the applied function.

Comment: Not work for me. `Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'rpush' command`.

Comment: Exactly as you type . There is no other code in my node js file.

Comment: Sorry, that is the problem with my redis server. I use it on window and can't execute `RPUSH` with multiple value.